# why is laravel 5 artisan migrate not creating sqlite database?

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to use `artisan migrate` to create tables in `sqlite`.

I have the following in database.php

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

and this is my migrate class `up` function

```
    Schema::connection('sqlite')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Note:- I have set DB_CONNECTION to be sqlite via the environment variable.

On the command line I get `nothing to migrate`, and no db is created (also no table).

Any ideas how I can get `artisan migrate` to create an `sqlite` db in `laravel 5`?

I have no problem creating `mysql` tables via artisan.

Thanks

Comment: What does `artisan migrate:status` show?

Comment: +------+--------------------------------------+
    | Ran? | Migration                            |
    +------+--------------------------------------+
    | Y    | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table |
    | Y    | 2016_07_01_101905_create_test_table  |
    +------+--------------------------------------+

Answer (score 7):

its because you didnt create the db. use `touch` command like this  to create new sqlite database.

```
touch database/database.sqlite
```

then configure the environment variable like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/absolute/path/to/database.sqlite
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I already tried that and it didn't work, besides sqlite creates a db file there isn't one.

Answer (score 4):

In order to answer this part of the OP's question:
"Any ideas how I can get artisan migrate to create an sqlite db in laravel 5?"

In some cases where deployment and migrations need to be scripted I use a [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers) to check the Sqlite DB exists and if not create it.

Here are the steps:

1) Create a Provider and save it to `app/Providers/SqliteServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SqliteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $databaseFile = config('database.connections.sqlite.database');
        if (!file_exists($databaseFile)) {
            info('Make Sqlite File "' . $databaseFile . '"');
            file_put_contents($databaseFile, '');
        }
    }
}
```

2) Register the provider in `config/app.php`. For example in a fresh L5.8 install the `SqliteServiceProvider` would be placed under the `RouteServiceProvider` like so:

```
'providers' => [

    //...

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\SqliteServiceProvider::class, // <--- HERE

],
```

3) Add/replace the following to the `'connections'` element of `config/database.php`

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_SQLITE_FILEPATH', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
],
```

4) In my `.env` file I add this:

```
DB_SQLITE_FILEPATH=/full/path/to/mysqlitefilename.sqlite
```

...but if you prefer you can skip this step and the DB will be created as `database/database.sqlite`.

5) Run your migration as usual and the sqlite file should be created then populated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. `artisan migrate` seems to ignore the `env DB_CONNECTION` and the database.php default (which reads the `env` anyway). Instead it like the `.env` file `DB_CONNECTION`, with this set to `sqlite` it works (plus, as mentioned above you do need to manually create the database file, which is a pain for making dbs on the fly.

Also means you can't really change artisan migrate database types (ie: `sqlite` and `mysql`) on the fly as you need to change the `.env` variable each time you change the target db type.

go laravel.

Comment: Why would you change .env variable each time? All you have to change is the target db and all settings will be picked up. You can give your variables names specific to the database. For example DB_SQLITE_DATABASE, DB_PGSQL_DATABASE, DB_PGSQ_USERNAME etc

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you need to create empty `database.sqlite` file.

You should also use `artisan --env` parameter if you want artisan to load the concrete .env file. For example, `artisan --env=testing migrate` will force artisan to load `.env.testing` file.

Comment: Nice custom env tip!